# Simulating argument-dependent lookup for template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup

I've encountered this problem while writing some library-like code recently, and I thought discussing it might help others as well.

Suppose I have a library with some function templates defined in a namespace. The function templates work on types supplied by client code, and their inner workings can be customized based on type traits defined for the client types. All client definitions are in other namespaces.

For the simplest example possible, a library function would basically have to look like this (note that all the code snippets are just wishful thinking, nothing compiles):

```
namespace lib
{
    template<typename T> void f()
    {
        std::cout << traits_for<T>::str() << '\n'; //Use the traits in some way.
    }
}
```

Client code would look like this:

```
namespace client
{
    struct A { };
    template<> std::string traits_for<A>::str() { return "trait value"; }
}
```

And then someone, somewhere could call

```
lib::f<client::A>();
```

and everything would magically work (the specialization of `lib::f()` would find the traits explicit specialization in the namespace where the template argument for `T` is declared, just like ADL does for functions and their arguments). The goal is to make it as easy as possible for client code to define those traits (there could be several) for each client class (there could be lots of those).

Let's see what we could do to make this work. The obvious thing is to define a traits class primary template in `lib`, and then explicitly specialize it for client types. But then clients can't define those explicit specializations in their own namespace; they have to exit it, at least up to the global namespace, define the explicit specialization, then re-enter the `client` namespace, which, for maximum fun, could be nested. I'd like to keep the trait definitions close to each client class definition, so this namespace juggling would have to be done near each class definition. Suddenly, a one-liner in client code has turned into a messy several-liner; not good.

To allow the traits to be defined in the `client` namespace, we could turn the traits class into a traits function, that could be called from `lib` like this:

```
traits_for(T())
```

but now we're creating an object of class `T` just to make ADL kick in. Such objects could be expensive to construct (or even impossible in some circumstances), so this isn't good either. We have to keep working with types only, not their instances.

Giving up and defining the traits as members of the client classes is not an option either.

Some plumbing required to make this work would be acceptable, as long as it doesn't complicate the definitions for each class and trait in the `client` namespace (write some code once, but not for every definition).

I've found a solution that satisfies these stringent requirements, and I'll write it up in an answer, but I'd like to find out what people think about this: alternatives, critique of my solution, comments about how all of this is either bleeding obvious or completely useless in practice, the works...

Comment: http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-8/true-story-i-will-always-find-you

Comment: @sbabbi Nice find. The same technique applied in a slightly different and more complex context. What can I say... great minds think alike :-)

Comment: Why not simply [nest the traits within the client class](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a20dc1dd597667a8)? If your goal is simply mapping from types to types, a member type (or typedef) is as simple as it gets.

Comment: @Casey It's true I didn't give any reasons for not wanting that, the question just says 'it's not an option', but I thought it was a reasonable requirement. With separate traits, `lib` code can also be customized for built-in types in a uniform way. Also, the client classes could be used in several different contexts in an application; interfacing with `lib` is only one of them. Keeping the core class definitions as simple as possible and not tying them to the requirements of specific library code (if at all possible) is another reason for using separate traits classes.

Answer (score 1):

To find a declaration based on some argument, ADL looks like the most promising direction. So, we'll have to use something like

```
template<typename T> ??? traits_helper(T);
```

But we can't create objects of type `T`, so this function should only appear as an unevaluated operand; `decltype` springs to mind. Ideally, we shouldn't even assume anything about `T`'s constructors, so `std::declval` could also be useful:

```
decltype(traits_helper(std::declval<T>()))
```

What could this do? Well, it could return the actual traits type if the helper would be declared like this:

```
template<typename T> traits_for<T> traits_helper(T);
```

We've just found a class template specialization in another namespace, based on the declaration of its argument.

EDIT: Based on a comment from Yakk, `traits_helper()` should take a `T&&`, to allow it to work if `T`'s move constructor is not available (the function may not actually be called, but the semantic constraints required for calling it must be met). This is reflected in the complete sample below.

All put together in a standalone example, it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

namespace lib
{
    //Make the syntax nicer for library code.
    template<typename T> using traits_for = decltype(traits_helper(std::declval<T>()));

    template<typename T> void f()
    {
        std::cout << traits_for<T>::str() << '\n';
    }
}

namespace client_1
{
    //The following two lines are needed only once in every client namespace.
    template<typename> struct traits_for { static std::string str(); };
    template<typename T> traits_for<T> traits_helper(T&&); //No definition needed.

    struct A { };
    template<> std::string traits_for<A>::str() { return "trait value for client_1::A"; }

    struct B { };
    template<> std::string traits_for<B>::str() { return "trait value for client_1::B"; }
}

namespace client_2
{
    //The following two lines are needed only once in every client namespace.
    template<typename> struct traits_for { static std::string str(); };
    template<typename T> traits_for<T> traits_helper(T&&); //No definition needed.

    struct A { };
    template<> std::string traits_for<A>::str() { return "trait value for client_2::A"; }
}

int main()
{
    lib::f<client_1::A>(); //Prints 'trait value for client_1::A'.
    lib::f<client_1::B>(); //Prints 'trait value for client_1::B'.
    lib::f<client_2::A>(); //Prints 'trait value for client_2::A'.
}
```

Note that no objects of type `T` or `traits_for<T>` are created; the `traits_helper` specialization is never called - only its declaration is used.

Comment: Why not take `T*` and pass `(T*)nullptr`?  Sure, not much different, but seems less ikky.

Comment: Hmm.  private copy ctor?

Comment: @Yakk Very good point on the private / deleted copy constructor; I overlooked that. It looks like `traits_helper()` should take a `T&&`. I prefer `T&&` and `std::declval()`; to me, *this* looks less icky, as I see `declval` as a standard way of saying 'don't attempt to construct this'; just personal preference.

Comment: Neither `client::traits_for` nor `client::traits_helper` needs to be a template, [you could eliminate some boilerplate](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f19bb4900e02a2a0).

Comment: @Casey Actually, by doing that, you're *adding* boilerplate. In your solution, for each class in `client`, we need to define the specific traits class, declare the traits helper function overload, then define the individual traits if necessary. Using the templates, as the comment says, those lines are only needed once.

Comment: @Casey I've added some code to the example to clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just requiring clients to throw their specializations in the right namespace? If they want to use their own, they can:

```
namespace client
{
    struct A { };

    struct traits_for_A {
        static std::string str() { return "trait value"; }
    };

}

namespace lib 
{
    template <>
    struct traits_for<client::A>
    : client::traits_for_A
    { };
}
```

Could even give your users a macro if you don't want them to write all that out:

```
#define PROVIDE_TRAITS_FOR(cls, traits) \
    namespace lib { \
        template <> struct traits_for<cls> : traits { }; \
    }
```

So the above can become

```
PROVIDE_TRAITS_FOR(client::A, client::traits_for_A)
```

Comment: Nothing's wrong with that, really, as mentioned in the question. Nothing, except more typing, uglier code, two places to keep track of for each traits class, and, well, macros (I can live with them, but I'd rather live without them if possible).

Answer (score 0):

ADL is awesome.  Keep it simple:

```
namespace lib {
  // helpers for client code:
  template<class T>
  struct default_traits{
    using some_type=void;
  };
  struct no_traits{};
  namespace details {
    template<class T,class=void>
    struct traits:lib::no_traits{};
    template<class T>
    struct traits<T,decltype(void(
      traits_func((T*)0)
    ))>:decltype(
      traits_func((T*)0)
    ){};
  }
  template<class T>
  struct traits:details::traits<T>{};
}
```

Now simply add in the type `Foo` namespace:

```
namespace bob{
  // use custom traits impl:
  struct foo{};
  struct foo_traits{
    using some_type=int;
  };
  foo_traits traits_func(foo const*);

  // use default traits impl:
  struct bar {};
  lib::default_traits<bar> traits_func(bar const*);

  // use SFINAE test for any type `T`:
  struct baz {};
  template<class T>
  std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_base_of<T,baz>{},
    lib::default_traits<T>
  >
  traits_func(T const*)

}
```

and we are done.  Defining `traits_func` that takes a pointer convertable from `foo*` is enough to inject the trait.

If you fail to write such an overload, we get an empty `traits`, which is SFINAE friendly.

You can return `lib::no_traits` in an overload to explicitly turn off support, or just don;t write an overload that matches a type.

Comment: A solution full of valuable alternatives; thank you. Deriving from something specified via `decltype` instead of using an alias is worth having as an option. Regarding `traits_func()` definitions, I'd rather omit them: if, for some reason, I end up using such a function in a context where it's evaluated, it means I'm using it for something different from its original purpose; that's fine, but I prefer being reminded of that by a compiler error message before deciding it's not a problem.

Comment: Does `struct no_traits` have any special use here?

Comment: Providing `default_traits` is a good idea. However, the implementation hinges on the default `traits_func()` being a template and the ones in client namespaces being normal functions. This is the part that I don't like: it means the client needs to declare `traits_func()`, besides `foo_traits`, for every `foo`; that's one complication I'd rather avoid. I'd rather go for allowing clients to derive from `default_traits` if they need defaults.

Comment: Also, if the client forgets to declare `traits_func()` for a `foo`, it will be silently mapped to `default_traits`. This may be a feature or a problem, but I'd rather go for making it explicit through a compiler error.

Comment: @bogan replace `details::default_traits` with `no_traits` above to make the default nothing.  It does not depend on anything not being not-a-template.  It does generate some unfortunate hard errors for types `X` with a `traits_func` in their namespace that does not match `X*`.  Hmm, I can fix that.  And remove the default, giving SFINAe friendly empty traits.

Comment: @bogan there, a variation that covers most of your issues.

Comment: What I meant by the previous solution depending on `traits_func` not being a template in the client namespace was that, because you had a `traits_func` template in `lib`, if the client also declared its `traits_func` as a template to avoid having to write it several times, the call to the function would be ambiguous. Anyway, in the new version there's no `traits_func` declaration in `lib` anymore, so that's fixed.

Comment: A good alternative with slightly different goals; worth having. I'm not sure the 'keep it simple' goal you stated in the beginning still applies, though :-)